# Finding the smallest and largest positive floating point numbers that a system can represent

Tags: floating-point, cpu-architecture

Assume the following representation for a floating point number: 
1 sign bit 
4 bits exponent 
4 bits significand 
Bias of 7 for the exponent (there is no implied 1 as in IEEE)

Given this information, how would I find the largest and smallest positive floating point numbers **(in binary)** that this system can support ?

I want the solution but i'm interested in the method. How do I use this information to get my result ?

Comment: There's not enough information here. Does this imaginary format support infinities, nans, zeros? gradual underflow? How are the significand bits interpreted: does the most significant significand bit have value `1` or value `0.5`? (For IEEE 754, that's known, but this isn't IEEE 754.) Some examples of bit strings and their corresponding values might help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the value is calculated by `mantissa * base ^ (exponent - bias)`

The highest values will have all bits true so`mantissa = exponent = 2^4 -1 = 15`

put that all together and we get the maximum:

```
15 * 2 ^ (15 - 7) = 
15 * 2 ^ 8 = 
15 * 256 = 
3840
```

the smallest would be where `mantissa = 0001` and `exponent = 0000` so:

```
1 * 2 ^ (0 - 7) = 
2 ^ -7 = 
0.0078125
```

Comment: why didn't you use 14 - 7, i thought the exponent was from 1 -  14 ?

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm: If you want to restrict the range of the exponent from 1 to 14, that's completely up to you (this is, after all, an imaginary format), and that's information you need to give in the question. The IEEE 754 formats reserve the highest and lowest exponents for infinities, nans, subnormals and zeros, but you don't tell us whether this format also does that (and if you don't have a hidden 1 bit, then it makes little sense to reserve the lowest exponent). As it is, the question is underspecified.

Comment: That is what I came up with too, but I deleted the answer again, because we don't know if, like for real float types, the top bit is regarded as `1.`, which would mean that the max value would be `480` only. We also don't know if subnormals are allowed (would not make much sense for this format, but hey, we don't *know*).